# I tried other ways, but I still made a mistake.TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, mysql

I tried to change the fields of the database,and modified the'sql'statement,
but I still reported errors.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pymysql
from log import *
#连接数据库
db = pymysql.connect('localhost', 'root', '123456', "test")
cursor = db.cursor()
def save_get_xici_log(log_data):
        #抓取日志存入数据库
        for data in log_data:
                status = log_data[0]
                thread_name = log_data[1]
                url = log_data[2]
                code = log_data[3]
                proxy = log_data[4]
                speedtime = log_data[5]
                memo = log_data[6]

                #status级别
                if status == 'sucess':
                        status = 1
                elif status == 'failed':
                        status = 0
                elif status == 'error':
                        status = -1
                else:
                        pass


                sql = "INSERT INTO get_xici(thread_name, url, proxy, status, code, speedtime, memo) VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%d', '%f', '%s')" (thread_name, url, proxy, status, code, speedtime, memo)
                try:
                        cursor.execute(sql)
                        db.commit()
                        log.logger.info('save_get_xici_log is sucess')
                except Exception as e:
                        db.rollback()
                        log.logger.debug('save_get_xici_log is error'+ ' '+ str(e))
        db.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
        log = Logger(r'/root/Project/freeProxy/log/save_mysql.log',level='debug')
        log_data = 'sucess', 'thread-1', 'baidu.com', 200, '1.1.1.1', 0.823132, '1'
        save_get_xici_log(log_data)


######### MYSQL desc get_xici; #######################
mysql> desc get_xici;
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| thread_name | varchar(20)      | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| url         | varchar(20)      | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| proxy       | varchar(20)      | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| status      | tinyint(2)       | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| code        | int(3)           | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| speedtime   | float(3,2)       | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| memo        | varchar(500)     | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| nowtime     | timestamp        | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

#

erroor message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "save_mysql.py", line 106,
>   in 
>       save_get_xici_log(log_data)   File "save_mysql.py", line 92, in save_get_xici_log
>       sql = "INSERT INTO get_xici(thread_name, url, proxy, status, code, speedtime, memo) VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%d', '%f', '%s')"
>   (thread_name, url, proxy, status, code, speedtime, memo) TypeError:
>   'str' object is not callable

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to add a `%` in between the string and the parameters on this this line:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO get_xici(thread_name, url, proxy, status, code, speedtime, memo) VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%d', '%f', '%s')" (thread_name, url, proxy, status, code, speedtime, memo)
```

to:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO get_xici(thread_name, url, proxy, status, code, speedtime, memo) VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%d', '%f', '%s')" % (thread_name, url, proxy, status, code, speedtime, memo)
```

In general though, you should use [prepared statements](http://zetcode.com/python/pymysql/) rather than string interpolation for generating SQL queries for security reasons (preventing SQL injection).

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want, I believe, to let the SQL driver do all the necessary conversion and to eliminate the possibility of SQL Injection attacks:

```
        sql = "INSERT INTO get_xici(thread_name, url, proxy, status, code, speedtime, memo) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
        try:
                cursor.execute(sql,  (thread_name, url, proxy, status, code, speedtime, memo))
                db.commit()
                log.logger.info('save_get_xici_log is sucess')
        except Exception as e:
                db.rollback()
                log.logger.debug('save_get_xici_log is error'+ ' '+ str(e)
```

Note that there are no quotes, that is *`* characters, around your parameter placeholders, which must all be `%s`. The actual parameter values are specified as either a `list` or `tuple` as the second argument to the `execute` method call on the `cursor` object.